# AWS EC2 Group did not stabilize

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to create an AWS instance.  I'm getting the following reported back from AWS and the health status is Gray.  I can't seem to make any changes until the environment is in a running state.

```
ERROR   Creating Auto Scaling group named: awseb-e-fcdhwhmgqt-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup-1EQ4RCX6NKYVU failed Reason: Group did not stabilize. {current/minSize/maxSize} group size = {0/1/1}. Failed Scaling Activity: Volume of size 20GB is smaller than snapshot 'snap-03314edec3c849944', expect size >= 30GB. Launching EC2 instance failed.
```

Comment: The error is actually this: "_Volume of size 20GB is smaller than snapshot 'snap-03314edec3c849944', expect size >= 30GB_."

Answer (score 1):

That is happening because you are selecting a size of 20 GB when you are creating the EC2 instance for a Snapshot "snap-03314edec3c849944". Check below screenshot where you can select bigger volume size.

[image]